# Laravel 6, calculate stock expiry

Tags: php, laravel

I have a product table which has `production_date`, `expiry_date` and other necessary fields. For the view of products, I have to show the product expiry date. I know that I have to calculate today's date and the production date. Here is the code I found. Please clear me where can I write the calculation code and how to get the production_date from DB.

```
$production_date = "2018-10-21";
$shelf_life =  7;
$expiry_date = Carbon::parse($production_date)->addDays(($shelf_life - 1));

$diff_day = Carbon::now()->diffInDays($expiry_date, false);
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do.  You say you have `expiry_date` in your DB table, so why do you need to calculate it?  Are you asking [how to get data from the DB](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#retrieving-models)?

Answer (score 0):

Select all products from DB table with the column production_date and compact the value with the page. and use the above code where you want to show. That means you can write the above code in blade file.